# how to control the response to a pre-flight request

Tags: cors

My browser is sending a buffer of data to my server. Unfortunately I have set the requestHeader to  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/json') with a POST. This is because I am using this var json = JSON.stringify(myArray) in my browser code to create a json buffer. So I am pretty much stuck sending a pre-flight request (due to my use of application/json). Now I am get an error back in my Extensions window:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://www.xxxubstantiation.com/xxx_crud/xxxit_backend/register' from 
origin 'chrome-extension://xxxgnodlhfmhghjhbkkkaaammfocdpib' has been 
blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

So I figure that I need to clean up the preflight response but I have no idea where that is coming from. My support at Bitnami told me that I can put the following line into the https.conf file:

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

But I already have that  and I don't see that I am setting any content type in the preflight response. Where is the preflight response being setup and how can I either remove it or fix it? Is there any document on how (aka where) to configure a pre-flight response?

Comment: That depends on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server needs to respond with the following in the Header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

And the response should be an HTTP 200.
The first header is the one which corresponds to the error message you got and should then disappear ...

--- EXTENDED ANSWER ---

**Check Headers of OPTIONS response:**

I guess you need to check if the OPTIONS request really sends back all required headers to successfully handle the preflight. So to see the headers of the OPTION request, you could **simulate** it:

```
curl  -i \
  -H "Origin: http://your-calling-domain.com/" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" \
  -X OPTIONS \
  https://the-api-endpoint-you-want-to-call/... \
```

Here an example for the github api:

```
curl  -i \
  -H "Origin: http://your-calling-domain.com/" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" \
  -X OPTIONS \
  https://api.github.com/users/sebhildebrandt/org \
```

Your OPTION REQUEST need to match with the RESPONSE headers ... more specifically:

- `Access-Control-Request-Method` need to match (be one of) `Access-Control-Allow-Method`
- `Access-Control-Request-Headers` need to match with (be one of) `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`
- `Origin` need to match with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Only when all three are fine, the preflight is successful and your POST request will be fired to the server.

**Enable CORS Headers on Apache:**

In your config file (for your site) or in .htaccess you need to add

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept,Authorization,Content-Type,Origin"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

In this case, the preflight would be valid for one day (86400 seconds)

Then you need to be sure, to enable headers on apache (linux based systems):

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

For Windows you would need:

- open `httpd.conf` at your `_apache_folder_/conf`
- uncomment `#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so`

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This should do the trick ...

Comment: I added those three to the bottom of the httpd.conf, rebooted the apache, but am still getting same error. What is controlling the preflight response?

Comment: @Richard Bernstein: which OS you are running?

Comment: I am running linux. Btw, I got it going. Your help on setting the preflight response in .Access was SUPER helpful. Thank you!  It seems that having another page from the same domain open in the browser hid the issue since that inhibited the preflight.